# Google Analytics Report Stops Working on drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, google-analytics

I am using this module for some time and it worked fine. But suddenly it stops fetching analytics data. When I saw the report, it was showing message as

Code: 403 - Error: Forbidden - Message: usageLimitsuserRateLimitExceededUnregUser Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign uphttps://code.google.com/apis/console

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that your application is not registered to use the google analytics api and so you were only having a low grace quota meant for testing and you have exceeded that. Check the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors) to know about this error message and how to enable the api in the console.